# Trouble selecting a single random row from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select a user at random from a very simple table for the purposes of generating sample data.

The table has just two columns, the integer primary key `users_id` which has all the values from 1 to 46 inclusive, and `uname` which is a `varchar(60)`.

The query

```
select relusers.uname from relusers where relusers.users_id=floor(rand()*46+1);
```

is returning multiple rows. Perhaps I've been staring at this for too long but I fail to see how the above query could ever return more than one row. floor() returns a single integer which is being compared to the primary key column. Including users_id in the selection shows multiple different IDs being selected. Zero rows as a result I can understand, but multiple? Any ideas?

Comment: somehow you are not executing the where clause...

Comment: I believe its recalculating rand for each row, so if you have 46 rows, it'll calc rand 46 times and return those rows for which it matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is returning multiple rows because `rand()` is evaluated on each row.  So, you have the change of multiple matches.  And a chance of no matches at all.

You can use your idea, but try it this way:

```
select relusers.uname
from relusers cross join
     (selext @rand := rand()) const
where relusers.users_id = floor(@rand*46+1);
```

This generates just one random value and hence just one row.  But, with only 46 rows, the `order by` method should perform well enough:

```
select relusers.uname
from relusers
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from relusers order by rand() limit 1
```

Comment: While this works (though I believe is potentially much slower for a large dataset - which I'm not using) - I'd love an explanation of what is wrong with my version.

Comment: Hi @BrianDeMilia - you're not new to the site... you should probably know that it's a good idea to include details of why your solution works to solve the problem - don't forget that a lot of n00bs will come to the question/answer and will want to understand why and how this works. :)