# Get random single row from mysql table with enumerated rows

Tags: mysql, random, row

I've got a table with auto-incremented ID in Mysql. I am always adding to this table, never deleting and setting the ID value to NULL so that I am pretty sure there are no holes. This is the table structure:

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
     `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `data1` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
     `data2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     UNIQUE KEY `data` (`data1`,`data2`)
   )

I want to pick up a random row from the table. I am using this:

```
select * from mytable where id=(select floor(1 + rand() * ((select max(id) from mytable) - 1)));
```

But sometimes I get nothing, sometimes one row, sometimes two. Replacing max(id) with count(*) or count(id) did not help. I understand it may be because rand() is evaluated for each row. As suggested in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622493/trouble-selecting-a-single-random-row-from-mysql-table), I used this query:

```
select * from mytable cross join (select @rand := rand()) const where id=floor(1 + @rand*((select count(*) from mytable)-1));
```

But I still get an empty set sometimes. Same goes for this:

```
select * from mytable cross join (select @rand := rand()) const where id=floor(@rand*(select count(*) from mytable)+1);
```

I am looking for a fast way to do this, so that it won't take a long on big tables. ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1 is not an option for me. Can't that be done with one query, can be?

Comment: The auto-increment setting goes up one every time an insert is attempted. If an insert fails, the setting is not reset. So if you have IDs 1-10 and the next 4 inserts fail, the next ID will be 15

Comment: I see, this makes holes. I think what I wish to do cannot be done simply in relational databases... Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a great way to do this. I have built an identity verification feature for one website. It would ask users to select their phone number and/or address from a list of 4 options. Instead of generating random fake numbers/addresses, I made an array of letters and would select one at random to use in a query. The query would get the phone number and address where the `username like '%A%'`. I would do that 3 times to have the correct value and 3 random ones.